# gstreamer -playing audio from a website.. buffering issue

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, gstreamer, buffering

I am trying to play a sound file using :

`gst-launch playbin uri="some URL"`  where, URL is the whole url of that file.

It plays this file, but there is buffering problem and I can't listen to most of the audio.

Is there a simple command line argument that will solve this buffering issue.

Example: use of appsrc to store a temporary buffer and then play it ... a code snippet would be appreciated!

note: I am on windows and the GStreamer installation only has some standard plugins. But it does have appsrc and appsink plugins.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gst-launch playbin2 uri="some URL" buffer-size=size` check `gst-inspect playbin2` for more properties of the `playbin2` element.

Comment: hi Johan, thanks for the reply. I tried using buffer-size argument and specified some arbitrary size as 100. But still getting the same effect where almost 95% of the sound is lost. I tried different buffer sizes ranging from 1 to 50K.it says pipeline Unexpected discontinuity in audio timestamps of more than half a second (0:00:04.465759637), resyncing... any suggestions
?

Comment: hey Johan, StackedCrooked, the buffer size of 512K worked! I was trying to play 11,025 Hz 16 bit PCM format,with a bit rate of 176kbps. Don't know exactly it is related, but choosng a differet format andlower bit rate solved the problem